# Phonegap Facebook Graph API Login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to login to facebook from my phonegap application, which uses angular.js and facebook graph api to do so. I have this in my controller:

```
try {
    fbService.login()
        .then(function () {
            alert('successful login');
        });
}
    catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
```

Of course, I have injected fbService in my scope, service is connected fine, this I know for sure, I have checked already. This is what I have in 'fbService':

```
try {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {

                    if (response.status === 'connected') {

                        uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                        accessToken =  response.authResponse.accessToken;

                        alert('already logged in ;)')
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    }
                    else {
                        FB.login(function (response){
                            status='connected';
                            alert('just logged in to facebook!');

                            deferred.resolve(response);
                        });
                    }
                });

            }
                catch (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }

            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

My problem is that I get absolutely NO alerts on my smartphone. I am sure it gets to this part of code in the controller (checked) and I am sure that the controller is accessing the service. The error must be somewhere in this code, I just can't find it. The try-catch blocks are not alerting anything... ;/

Comment: Have a look at this http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/.

Comment: I read this, but I want to upload a picture to user's album, which I think is not a function openFB has. My question it, is it possible using the javascript SDK

Comment: You surely can. You need to get the right permissions for the action. For uploading a photograph you need the publish_actions and user_photos permission.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios

Comment: Yeah, I read about this. My problem is that I can't get this login to work in cordova. Can you help me out, please?

Comment: Just reconfirm that you have initialised the SDK using init().

Comment: Yes, I have. I think I know the problem now, but do not have any idea how to solve it. You have to add a platform and domain to run the application in a browser, otherwise the FB.getLoginStatus does not fire its callback, but how do I add a platform/domain for cordova?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58922/discussion-between-nathvarun-and-user3127242).

Comment: Answer you a while ago ;)